# $(this) selector works in jsfiddle but not on my script

Tags: jquery, this, argument-passing, replacewith

See jsfiddle example... http://jsfiddle.net/nnmEY/21/

Objective...

Modify textarea via the select menu and or via direct input and have the textarea value passed on to the div.

Issues...

1.) The script at the very bottom of the example below works fine in jsfiddle but not in the example.

2.) I'm also trying to figure the best logic for first script on how to convert "\n" to "br" when passing value from .ta(textarea) to .tatx(div text). You can see the problem when you select three or more options in the select menu. I'm thinking replaceWith() but I have not been able to make it work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    li {margin-bottom:7px; background:#DDD; padding:5px;}
    #par {width:350px;}
    .tatx {color:#C00;}
</style>

<div id="par">
<ul>

<li>
Select an option, then, select another option.<br>
<select class="sl">
    <option value="item 1">option 1</option>
    <option value="item 2">option 2</option>
    <option value="item 3">option 3</option>
</select><br>
<p>Selected options values are passed to textarea<br>
<textarea class="ta"></textarea>
<p>Textarea value is passed to div as text
<div class="tatx">Div Text</div>
</li>
<li>
Select an option, then, select another option.<br>
<select class="sl">
    <option value="item 1">option 1</option>
    <option value="item 2">option 2</option>
    <option value="item 3">option 3</option>
</select><br>
<p>Selected options values are passed to textarea<br>
<textarea class="ta"></textarea>
<p>Textarea value is passed to div as text
<div class="tatx">Div Text</div>
</li>
<li>
Select an option, then, select another option.<br>
<select class="sl">
    <option value="item 1">option 1</option>
    <option value="item 2">option 2</option>
    <option value="item 3">option 3</option>
</select><br>
<p>Selected options values are passed to textarea<br>
<textarea class="ta"></textarea>
<p>Textarea value is passed to div as text
<div class="tatx">Div Text</div>
</li>

</ul>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li > .sl').on('change', function() {
    var taVal = $(this).siblings().find('.ta').val();
    var tatxVal = $(this).siblings('.tatx').html()
    var slVal = $(this).val() + '\n';
    var slHtml = $(this).val() + '<br>';
    $(this).siblings().find('.ta').val(slVal + taVal);
    $(this).siblings('.tatx').html(slHtml + taVal);
});
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li > .ta').keyup(function(){
        $(this).next('.tatx').html($(this).val());
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.ta` is not a sibling of `.sl`

Comment: @RichardA Where does his code say `.ta` and `.sl` are siblings? `.find('.ta')` looks for descendants, not siblings.

Comment: @Barmar Oh yeah, does too. I missed that.

Comment: I think you posted the wrong fiddle link, there's no select menu there. Why not use a Stack Snippet here instead of jsfiddle?

Comment: If it works in jsfiddle but not your site, you must be doing something different. But there's no way for us to know what you're doing differently.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site so we can see it failing?

Comment: Which part of the script isn't working?

Comment: the last example as you mentioned works okay. I still don't get it

Comment: In the jsfiddle example; if you type in the textarea div is updated. In the example code I posted it does not update the div when you type in the textarea you can see the script is identical. For clarification I want to update the div using both the select menu and diurect input into the textarea

Comment: In the jsfiddle example; if you type in the textarea, the div is updated. In the example code I posted it does not update the div when you type in the textarea, You can see the script is identical. For clarification... I want to update the DIV text using either the select menu and or directly entering text into the textarea. The select menu works, entering data manually in the textarea does not.

Comment: I just found that you mistyped the selector. check the answer

Comment: why to be closed this question? -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's no anything wrong with jsfiddle sample. you **mistyped** it. Therefore it called undefined. perhaps, this is what you mean?

Here's your script and it works well:

```
<div id="par">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>Selected options values are passed to textarea</p>
            <select class="sl">
                <option value="item 1">option 1</option>
                <option value="item 2">option 2</option>
                <option value="item 3">option 3</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <br />
            <p>Selected options values are passed to textarea</p>
            <textarea class="ta"></textarea>
            <div class="tatx">Div Text</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Selected options values are passed to textarea</p>
            <select class="sl">
                <option value="item 1">option 1</option>
                <option value="item 2">option 2</option>
                <option value="item 3">option 3</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <br />
            <p>Selected options values are passed to textarea</p>
            <textarea class="ta"></textarea>
            <div class="tatx">Div Text</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Selected options values are passed to textarea</p>
            <select class="sl">
                <option value="item 1">option 1</option>
                <option value="item 2">option 2</option>
                <option value="item 3">option 3</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <br />
            <p>Selected options values are passed to textarea</p>
            <textarea class="ta"></textarea>
            <div class="tatx">Div Text</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li > .ta").keyup(function () {
            $(this).next('.tatx').html($(this).val());
        })
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li > .sl').on('change', function () {
            var taVal = $(this).siblings().find('.ta').val();
            var tatxVal = $(this).siblings('.tatx').html();
            var slVal = $(this).val() + '\n';
            var slHtml = $(this).val() + '\n'+'<br />';
            $(this).siblings().find('.ta').val(slVal + taVal);
            $(this).siblings('.tatx').html(slHtml + tatxVal);
        });
    });
</script>
```

To see the demo, check again [here](http://appacyber.net/appalab/script_testz/test2.html). or in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alicera/gfxrmks1/).

Comment: Thank you Jean for giving this some time. I hate it when I miss typos.

Comment: yeah, sometimes, I mistyped too .. that's human .. just keep optimistic and spirit

Comment: I dropped the .find() from the script and it now updates both the textarea and the div. thanks again.

Comment: One last comment for those who are interested. I changed next() in the first script to siblings and all works as intended.